# How to Convert this Statement into XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
var FullName = String.Format("{0} {1}", "FirstName", "LastName");
```

How to translate to a TextBlock text?

```
<TextBlock Text="" />
```

Comment: You could have a property in your binding that returns that formatted string, and bind the TextBlock Text property to that property in your binding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`StringFormat` to the rescue:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
            <Binding Path="FirstName" />
            <Binding Path="LastName" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

If you are wondering what the first `{}` does, it is to prevent WPF from thinking the first `{0}` is a `MarkupExtension`.

Comment: Yeah, this wasn't available in the first release of WPF. And it only works when the target property is a `string`. But otherwise, it is great!

Comment: Using the aPaths won't yield any results since there are no actual Paths. For this to work out of the box, I removed the Paths and added <Binding FallbackValue="FirstName" /> <Binding FallbackValue="LastName" />

Comment: Okay, well, I was just assuming that is what you needed, as your question wasn't really clear why you were trying to format a string like that. If all you want to do is print out "FirstName LastName", you should just set the `Text` property to that directly. If you still want to do the `MultiBinding`, you can set the `Source` of the `Binding`. The `FallbackValue` is used when the `Binding` fails, or returns null.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the identifier is for the TextBlock element, you need to use that in your code and do something along the lines of:

```
TextBlockVariable.Text = FullName;
```

Comment: I think the asker is looking for a solution similar to the one Abe Heidebrecht posted, where you use XAML to achieve the string format, but there is not enough information in the question to tell for sure.